# Storing result from API call to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I'm having trouble storing the result from this fetch to an array:

```
const words = []
fetch("https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=100")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .then(function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      words.push(data.result[i])
      console.log(words)
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
let promise = fetch("https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com//word?number=10")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you want to call `response.json()` instead since the data returned is json
The data is in the `result` parameter after, you can iterate through this array to get the words.

```js
const words = []
fetch("https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=100")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log('Result', result)
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      words.push(result[i])
    }
    console.log('Words', words)
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're planning on storing the words array might be problematic because you can't control how long the fetch will take.
Usually you'd store the result of the promise in a variable an control that after the promise has settled:

```js
const words = fetch("https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=100")
  .then(response => response.json())


words
  .then(x => {
    console.log('the promise has settled', x)
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```